# How to create multiple relations with same object property?

Tags: ontology, protege

I am using protege 5 for developing ontology. I have created `has_composition` as object property. In my ontology the same object_property is used for different domains and their respective range, like `has_composition` of A is B and `has_composition` of C and D is E and F.

How can I model this mapping??

Comment: Have you read any of the manuals? http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk/protegeowltutorial/resources/ProtegeOWLTutorialP4_v1_3.pdf It doesn't matter what version you use, the strategy is always the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OWL (Ontology Web Language, the ontology that defines ontologies) does not allow to model what you're trying to do.

A workaround I can think of is to use sub-properties. Imagine the following classes:

- `Pizza`
- `TomatoSauce`
- `ChocolateCake`
- `Chocolate`

If you want to define relations such as

- A `Pizza` `has_composition` `TomatoSauce`, and
- A `ChocolateCake` `has_composition` `Chocolate`

then define the following relations:

- `has_composition`: No domain nor range (or a common superclass such as `Dish` and `Ingredient` for example)

  - `has_tomato_sauce`: Domain `Pizza`, range `TomatoSauce`
  - `has_chocolate`: Domain `ChocolateCake`, range `Chocolate`

This will allow the reasoner (the software that computes inferences) to infer that if `something` `has_chocolate` `a_chocolate`, then

- `something` `rdf:type` `Chocolate` (inferred by the domain of `has_chocolate`);
- `something` `has_composition` `a_chocolate` (because `has_chocolate` is a sub-property of `has_composition`).

---

You can check out this example in [this Gist I made](https://gist.github.com/Richard-Degenne/604976f9f41c030d86a1af2ef1fb2e8b).

Download it, open it, and start the reasoner. You will see the inferred statements in yellow.

[image: Screenshot of inferred statements]